# Component template inheritance/composition

Tags: angular

How is one supposed to share duplicate UI functionality among Angular components?

Angular makes this very tedious through view encapsulation. You cannot share styles between components unless you make them global, breaking view encapsulation, which is a bad Angular practice. The only way I can think of is through content projection, but this leads to very flat component structures and you still can't share SCSS.

Take the following example:

[image: UI Example]

I've got two types of "Cards". The first one is unique, and the second may repeat.

form-card.component.html

```
<mat-card class="crm-form-card" matRipple>
  <div class="crm-form-card-container">
    <mat-card-content class="crm-form-card-content">
      <mat-icon>{{ icon }}</mat-icon>
    </mat-card-content>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

form-card.component.scss

```
@import 'abstracts/variables';

:host {
  height: 100%;
}

.crm-form-card,
.crm-form-card-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.crm-form-card {
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.crm-form-card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.crm-form-card,
.crm-form-card-content {
  margin: 0;
}
```

form-card-edit.component.html

```
<mat-card class="crm-form-card" matRipple>
  <div class="crm-form-card-container">
    <mat-card-title
      class="crm-form-card-title"
      crmDisableEventPropagation="mousedown"
    >
      Form 1
    </mat-card-title>
    <div class="crm-form-card-options">
      <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Filter 1</button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-menu-item>Filter 2</button>
      </mat-menu>

      <button
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"
        mat-icon-button
        crmDisableEventPropagation="mousedown"
      >
        <mat-icon>more_horiz</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <mat-card-content class="crm-form-card-content">
      <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions
      class="crm-form-card-actions"
      crmDisableEventPropagation="mousedown"
    >
      Created 03/06/19
    </mat-card-actions>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

form-card-edit.component.scss

```
@import 'abstracts/variables';

:host {
  height: 100%;
}

.crm-form-card,
.crm-form-card-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.crm-form-card {
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.crm-form-card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    'title options'
    'edit .'
    'actions .';
}

.crm-form-card-title,
.crm-form-card-actions {
  padding: $charm-spacing-small;
}

.crm-form-card-title {
  grid-area: title;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  justify-self: start;


align-self: start;
}

.crm-form-card-options {
  grid-area: options;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: start;
  padding: 4px;
}

.crm-form-card-content {
  grid-area: edit / span 2;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.crm-form-card-actions {
  grid-area: actions / span 2;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: end;
}

.mat-card,
.crm-form-card-title,
.crm-form-card-content,
.crm-form-card-actions {
  margin: 0;
}
```

They share a good amount of SASS and HTML.

Comment: Might be I am not very clear with your question, but why don't you create common SCSS/CSS file for both (every) shared component and inject throughout the all shared components, given you can add multiple CSS files in `styleUrls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using content projection along with `select` and the deprecated `:host ::ng-deep` to solve my issue.

form-card.component.html

```
<mat-card class="crm-form-card" matRipple>
  <div class="crm-form-card-container">
    <ng-content select=".crm-form-card-title"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".crm-form-card-options"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".crm-form-card-content"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".crm-form-card-actions"></ng-content>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

form-card-add.component.html

```
<crm-form-card>
  <mat-card-content class="crm-form-card-content">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  </mat-card-content>
</crm-form-card>
```